# How to properly use template class with an abstract pointer type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I created a List with a template Node class to hold different data types such as Node<int> but also more complex types such as Node<BaseEvent*>.

I also have an event container class to hold different event objects so it has a member argument

```
List<BaseEvent*> events;
```

where BaseEvent is an abstract class with derived classes that are not abstract.

In the event container I have a method called "add" (see below) that adds a new event to that events.

```
BaseEvent* eventClone = event.clone();
```

The clone returns a pointer to a new derived object such as:

```
new OpenEvent(*this);
```

Once it calls the list's insert method, it instantiates a new Node (see below), and in the Node constructor it assigns the value like so:

```
value(new T(new_value))
```

So basically it allocates a pointer memory (T=BaseEvent*).

I think I might be losing the eventClone pointer and have a memory leak.
The problem is that when I debugged it I saw that both: `T* value;` (aka `BaseEvent** value`) and `BaseEvent* eventClone` have the same address in memory.

I'm not sure if when I do `delete value` in the destructor of Node it will just free the pointer allocation to BaseEvent* or also the data that it holds.

Any insights are welcome!

---

**Relevant code snippets**

Node<T>

```
    template <class T>
    class Node
    {
    public:

        Node(const T& new_value, Node* new_next = NULL, Node* new_prev = NULL);
        ~Node();

        const T& getValue() const;
        Node<T>* getNext() const;
        Node<T>* getPrev() const;
        void setNext(Node* node);
        void setPrev(Node* node);

    private:
        T* value;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
    };

    template <class T>
    Node<T>::Node(const T& new_value, Node* new_next, Node* new_prev) : 
        value(new T(new_value)) 
    {
        next = new_next;
        prev = new_prev;
    }

    template <class T>
    Node<T>::~Node()
    {
        delete value;
    }
    ...
```

Linked list that uses Node<T>

```
    template <class T>
    class List
    {
    public:
        List();
        ~List();
        
        int getSize() const;
        Node<T>* getFirst() const;
        Node<T>* getNext(Node<T>& node) const;
        Node<T>* getPrev(Node<T>& node) const;
        void insertStart(const T& data);
        void insertLast(const T& data);
        void insertAfter(Node<T>& target, const T& data);
        void insertBefore(Node<T>& target, const T& data);
        void removeNode(Node<T>& node);
        bool contains(const T data);


    private:
        Node<T>* head;
        int size;
    };

    template <class T>
    List<T>::List() : head(NULL), size(0)
    {
    }

    template <class T>
    List<T>::~List()
    {
        Node<T>* temp;
        while (head)
        {
            temp = head;
            head = head->getNext();
            delete temp;
            size--;
        }
    }
    ...
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::insertStart(const T& data) {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(data);
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(data, head);
            head->setPrev(temp);
            head = temp;
        }

        size++;
    }
    ...
```

The event container class:

```
    class EventContainer
    {
    public:
        EventContainer() :
            events(List<BaseEvent*>()) {}
        ~EventContainer() {}

        virtual void add(const BaseEvent&);
        
        class EventIterator
        {
        public:
            EventIterator() :
                current(NULL) {}
            EventIterator(Node<BaseEvent*>& node) :
                current(&node) {}
            EventIterator(Node<BaseEvent*>* node) :
                current(node) {}
            ~EventIterator() {}

            EventIterator& operator=(const EventIterator& nodeIterator) {
                current = nodeIterator.current;
                return *this;
            }
            EventIterator& operator++() {
                current = current->getNext();
                return *this;
            }
            BaseEvent& operator*() const {
                return *(current->getValue());
            }

            friend bool operator==(const EventIterator& iterator1, const EventIterator& iterator2) {
                return iterator1.current == iterator2.current;
            }

            bool operator!=(const EventIterator& iterator) const {
                return !(*this == iterator);
            }

        private:
            Node<BaseEvent*>* current;
        };

        virtual EventIterator begin() const;
        virtual EventIterator end() const;

    private:
        List<BaseEvent*> events;
    };
```

The implementation of `add` method:

```
    void EventContainer::add(const BaseEvent& event) {
        BaseEvent* eventClone = event.clone();
        if (events.getSize() == 0)
        {
            events.insertStart(eventClone);
            return;
        }

        Node<BaseEvent*>* current = events.getFirst();
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (*eventClone < *(current->getValue()))
            {
                events.insertBefore(*current, eventClone);
                return;
            }
            current = current->getNext();
        }

        events.insertLast(eventClone);
    }

    EventContainer::EventIterator EventContainer::begin() const {
        return events.getFirst();
    }
    
    EventContainer::EventIterator EventContainer::end() const {
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: You need to be explicit about what code owns what data; one clear way is to stop using raw pointers in ownership situations.

Comment: Node should hold pointer to data. But because EventContainer holds BaseEvent* type i cant create another constructor that accepts T*.. and then just assign the data member in Node to that pointer

Comment: If you have `List<BaseEvent*>`, then this expression `value(new T(new_value)) ` is `value(new BaseEvent*(ptr to baseevent))`, and the type of your `value` is `BaseEvent**`. So, doesn't make much sense to me, better to have your `Node` to keep `T` as value, not as ptr. Then if your class is non-copyable it's OK, just store pointers (but not pointers to pointers).

Comment: @pptaszni But then in the constructor the expression would be `value(new_value)`. so I won't be able to do `delete value;` in the Node's destructor (it would error `cannot delete objects that are not pointers`). and I kinda must work with pointers because BaseEvent is abstract.

Comment: Does node own the data of type T?  Ok, it can hold a pointer or not, but it should not be a raw pointer.  Storing ownership in raw pointers is unclear and buggy.  Next, if you are storing `Foo*`s, who is owning the pointed to `Foo`?  It shouldn't be a raw pointer that owns the pointed to resource in 999/1000 pieces of code.  Until you **decide** what variables own what, your code will only be "correct" by accident.

Comment: Replace *every owning pointer* with a unique ptr.  This will transform runtime bugs to compile time bugs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont if you look in the code snippets, Node holds pointer to a copy of `new_value`, so it's not being pointed to by different pointers. The only problem is when I use `event.clone()` which instantiates a new event of type `BaseEvent*` (abstract) and then I insert it into the event list. I'm not sure how to change Node to comply with this, since `value` is of type `BaseEvent**` in this case..

Comment: You'll have to markup the transfer of ownership with std move, and change some `const&` to `&&` or not references at all.  Now your code describes who owns what.  Then problems you can't solve with simple type changes and owership move transfer will reflect bugs in lifetime management in your code.  I don't have the brain power to manage complex lifetime proofs of code like that with ease and accuracy; so offload it to the C++ type system.  This is *how* to solve your problem, not *here is your solution*.  I don't know what your solition is, I just know how to fix it.  Feel free not to.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to change Node to comply with this, since value is of type BaseEvent** in this case."  <-- yeah, that's why I wrote it doesn't make sense. Don't impl your `Node` to hold the ptrs. If later on user decides that he doesn't want to hold copies, he can use `List<Whatever*>` or `List<Whatever&>`. Also take the advices from other comments and use smart pointers. E.g. in you can use `List<std::unique_ptr<EventBase> >`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think you suggest to change `T* value;` to `T value`? I tried that, but then got error in `delete value` the Node destructor: `cannot delete objects that are not pointers`. (@pptaszni I can't use STL in this part, so no smart pointers). If I do use `T value` where in some cases `T=int` and others `T=BaseEvent*`, where do I call `delete value`? it can't be in Node in this case, but that's where I hold the data. (Thank you both for the help so far!)

Comment: Please look up `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::shared_ptr<T>`. Also, read up about RAII and automatic storage duration. If you have a member with automatic storage duration, i.e. `T value`, you don't have to delete it.

Comment: I found a go-around solution - instead of accepting `const T& new_value` in the Node constructor. I accept `T* new_value`, and assign `value(new_value)` (+ minor changes in the List code), so all memory allocations are being done when I want to insert something into a list. This works because this List is invisible to the naive user, since it's only being used by the events and event containers. The only cons are that it has to pass pointer to allocated object. But with some extra work and a new constructor and functions I can probably have it accepting a reference and allocate memory for it.

Comment: No, I suggested replacing every pointer that "owns" (has responsibility for lifetime of) the data it points to with a unique_ptr.  This includes both structure members and function arguments.